# How do I make all sections of a website have the scroll-over effect?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a website and wanted to have a "scroll-over" effect for the different sections of my website. If you don't know what I mean by the "scroll-over" effect, please visit https://sevenbits.github.io/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader/ and scroll down slightly. The successor sections scroll over their predecessors, which become fixed when they reach the top.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this with every section, and not only the top one. It would be great if this could be a short amount of code, but it would also be OK if it was a lot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you inspect the blue backgroudn you will see:.splash-container {
    background: #1f8dd6;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 88%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed !important;

Comment: @DavidB I noticed that, but since that one section is fixed, it can't be scrolled. I want the successor sections to move, and then be fixed when they hit the navigation bar at the top of the screen. I was trying to figure out if this was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: #446;
  z-index: 100;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.splash {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 20vh;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #8ef;
  z-index: 0;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 80vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 50;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navbar"></div>
  <div class="splash"></div>
</header>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now.

Comment: Do you need the `position: relative;` for `body`? If so, please explain why.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but that only works for the one splash part at the top. When an image hits the top, I want it to obtain the splash class. How do I do this?

Comment: if u use position: absolute, position: relative for parrent element set coords 0,0. otherwise 0,0 place at left top angle in u browser.

Comment: Oh... Thanks. Didn't understand the code when I first read it. After I finish checking to make sure it works as I want, I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: i dont understand this question. english is not native to me